# MySQL: Out of Memory / MariaDB

Tags: mysql, wordpress, debian, innodb, mariadb

**Hello dear Stackers!**

I am having an Issue with my **Debian 8** Server VServer (**1GB Ram, CPU 2x1GHz**) Shared. **MariaDB**.
I got three **Wordpress** installation that needs to keep running, and a **few other Websites**. And I cannot figure out what the issue is, this happens every few days, or when a bunch of Clients browser the Wordpress site at once.

I get the error that **Wordpress isn't able to connect to the Database** (because the **DB crashed**).

I tried a bunch  of different things, one is **disabling Performance Schema** (= off), which does not change anything. I also changed the **MySQL** to **Mixed**, which solved a few warnings (not sure if dirty fix).
Wordpress could not solve the issues by fixing the DB automatically (no errors found).

Thanks in advance! :)

*A part of the my.cnf:*

```
(...)
max_connections         = 100
connect_timeout         = 5
wait_timeout            = 600
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size        = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size          = 32M
max_heap_table_size     = 32M

(...)

# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files       = 400
innodb_io_capacity      = 400
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT
(...)
```

---

*Journalctl*

```
(...)
Apr 17 23:07:39 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[618]: 2017-04-17 23:07:39 139847238380288 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. The statement is unsafe beca
Apr 17 23:20:33 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[618]: 2017-04-17 23:20:33 139847221811968 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. The statement is unsafe beca
Apr 18 00:01:56 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[618]: 2017-04-18  0:01:56 139847220599552 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. The statement is unsafe beca
Apr 18 00:07:46 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Apr 18 00:07:46 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Apr 18 00:07:51 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: mariadb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 18 00:07:51 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB database server...
Apr 18 00:07:51 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Apr 18 00:07:51 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:51 140160371898304 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.14-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 2956 ...
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: InnoDB: mmap(276824064 bytes) failed; errno 12
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128663552 bytes)
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP mysqld[2956]: 2017-04-18  0:07:52 140160371898304 [ERROR] Aborting
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Apr 18 00:07:52 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
(MANUALLY RESTARTED SERVER)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 GB is not much these days. You can still run MariaDB 10.1 on a 1G host of course, but you need to make some adjustments to your configuration file.

Below are some examples how to reduce the memory usage on MariaDB *server startup*.

Please note that there are different parameters which affect memory usage upon client connections and query execution, but your error log indicates that you are getting the problem on startup.

Please also note that not all of these variables can be reduced at once, and not always can you choose the minimal value. There is no one-for-all advice, it depends on which engines you use, and how you use them. Check documentation for every variable that you intend to adjust to understand what exactly it affects.

Finally, since you have not quoted the whole config, it is possible that you have some other options that actually increase the memory usage. Notes below are based on hardcoded defaults.

Here is my 10.1.21 server started with all defaults (no config options) on a new clean datadir:

**ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS**

```
  VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
747040  95108  14756 mysqld
```

It is a baseline for all memory usage examples below.

#### innodb_buffer_pool_size

The default value in 10.1 is 128M. You increased it to 256M, so you lose 128M on it:

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + **`--innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M`***

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  888608 104856  14820 mysqld
```

Instead, you can reduce it, the minimal possible value is 5M:

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + **`--innodb_buffer_pool_size=5M`***

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  606752  85928  14848 mysqld
```

#### aria_pagecache_buffer_size

The default value is 128M, the minimum is 128K:

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + **`--aria-pagecache-buffer-size=128K`***

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  611872  90004  14932 mysqld
```

#### key_buffer_size

The default value is 128M, minimum according to documentation is 8 (*although on my machine everything below 4K is adjusted to 0*):

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + **`--key_buffer_size=8`***

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  611872  71264  14748 mysqld
```

#### innodb_log_buffer_size

The default value is 16M, minimum is 256K:

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + **`--innodb_log_buffer_size=256K`***

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  718368  74980  14756 mysqld
```

#### Binary log

You mentioned that you "changed the MySQL to Mixed", and it allowed to get rid of some warnings. Apparently it means that you set `binlog_format=mixed`, and that you have `log-bin` enabled (it is disabled by default). Adjusting the binary log format to `MIXED` is fine, but the binary logging itself uses some memory, even in default configuration:

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + **`--log-bin`***

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  747312  95240  14820 mysqld
```

If you don't need it, you can disable it, it will save you a little bit of memory, and will improve the performance.

#### The whole InnoDB

In the unlikely case that you don't need InnoDB at all, you can disable it, it will save you a lot of memory:

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + **`--skip-innodb --default-storage-engine=MyISAM`***

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  383948  55696  12668 mysqld
```

#### ALL TOGETHER NOW

So, hypothetically, if you do all of that at once (which you should **not**!), you can decrease the initial memory allocation significantly:

*ALL DEFAULT OPTIONS + `--aria-pagecache-buffer-size=128K --innodb_log_buffer_size=256K --key_buffer_size=8 --innodb_buffer_pool_size=5M --skip-innodb --default-storage-engine=MyISAM`*

```
    VIRT    RES    SHR COMMAND
  113612  26572  12784 mysqld
```

Comment: I now first added a 1GB swap file, I will see how that helps. After that I will do these changes, if it turns out to stil crash.
I was in believ to already have had installed a swap drive/file - must have been on one of the other servers.

thanks

Comment: Yes, having a swap file should let it work, but...  MySQL performance suffers severely when it swaps.  Consider cutting in half any setting that looks like a "size".

Comment: wasn't enough. I now set a few of the above mentioned settings, and will see how that works. If it crashes again I will come back again ;)

Comment: It would be good to set up a monitor (something simple, even just `top`), to see the dynamics -- how much the server takes when it starts vs how big it is before it dies. Maybe you're encountering a leak.